# Why is my total not being calculated and processed into output?

Tags: python

Brand new to Python and taking a college course on it. This program is supposed to display a user's total hours based on the input for hours and the input for the hourly rate. I'm getting a Traceback Error on line 14. I might not be fully understanding out the try function works. Any assistance is highly appreciated!

CURRENT BUILD:

```
    hrwk = input('Please enter the number of hours worked this week: ')
try:
    hrwkval = int(hrwk)
except:
    hrwkval = -1
if hrwkval > 0 :
    print = hrate = input('Please enter your hourly rate: ')
try:
    hrateval = int(hrate)
except:
    hrateval = -1
if hrateval > 0:
    total = float(hrwk)*float(hrate)
    print(total)
else:
    print('Error: Please use numerical inputs. Example: 40, 35.3')
```

Comment: Wrong syntax here `print = hrate = input('Please enter your hourly rate: ')`. Should be `hrate = input('Please enter your hourly rate: ')` and then `print(hrate)`.

Comment: There's a number of errors and problems here. The first line is incorrectly indented. The `try .. except` are not specific about what exception they catch, so other errors will go unnoticed. You're assigning to `print` (`print =`). You're converting two entered values into integers, but then proceed to convert them into floating point values - however, the text at the end suggests floating point inputs are valid. You only assign a value to `hrate` if `hrwkval` is greater than zero, so it may be undefined when it gets used. Start with a shorter program, fix problems before writing more code.

Comment: By the way, it's not a 'Traceback error', but when an error occurs at runtime, Python provides you with a traceback for that error that shows you exactly where the program was at when the error occurred - this is handy when your programs get longer and more complicated.

Comment: Thank you for this input. It's helped clarify this process and helps me further understand what I the code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you have a syntax error (incorrect way of using print statement in python).

This statement is incorrect:

```
    print = hrate = input('Please enter your hourly rate: ')
```

Instead, it should be:

```
    hrate = input('Please enter your hourly rate: ')
```

You cannot assign `hrate` to `print`.

Your fixed code is as follows:

```
hrwk = input('Please enter the number of hours worked this week: ')

try:
    hrwkval = int(hrwk)
except:
    hrwkval = -1

if hrwkval > 0 :
    hrate = input('Please enter your hourly rate: ')

try:
    hrateval = int(hrate)
except:
    hrateval = -1

if hrateval > 0:
    total = float(hrwk)*float(hrate)
    print(total)
else:
    print('Error: Please use numerical inputs. Example: 40, 35.3')
```

Comment: While this code does solve the error handling, there are some challenges with this code. Your second try statement will go to except if the first one was not an integer. The reason is `hrate` never got defined. So as you start to build your programming logic, look at options to solve for it as well. If you need help understanding try-except, let me know

Comment: If this helped solve the issue, please feel free to upvote the answer.

Comment: It sure did! The input from everyone helped clarify this process! Highly appreciate it and I did give this an upvote!